# Ajax on Chrome Extension Uninstall

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, uninstallation

I need to run an AJAX query to clean up my database when my Chrome extension is uninstalled. The `chrome.management.onUninstalled` function is for all installed extensions and I don't want to create a solution that uses it because it requires a special permission.

**How do I detect when only my extension is uninstalled.**

Comment: See [chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL).

Comment: Ok, I could just try a GET with that.